Error running exe in .net 8.0, dll runs fine
Having a problem running an .net 8.0 executable from the command line (pwsh) on a specific server.
This works:
dotnet run foo.dll

This fails:
.\foo.exe

The failure is stating that I must install the .net framework, which is absolute BS.  I have a few other apps with almost identical to this one and those run from the exe just fine.
Here is the start of the csproj file for this one and for the ones which have no problem:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

As you can see this is told to build an output of type exe, which appears to create an exe file that you can just run. And this is true for all the other projects.  And also was true for this project back when we were on .Net 7.0  But none of the other projects appear to have this issue.
This is very difficult to find assistance on, since "running exe" is a poor search term.
Has anyone besides everyone on my team ever seen this issue?  These are command line applications.  And this one is behaving differently.

How did you bundle the exe

Just copy/paste the output files from the build to the new machine

I would run a publish

Any idea why dotnet publish is different from dotnet build and why that would make a difference?
